# terminate called after throwing an instance of 'rosbag::BagIOException' what(): Error opening file:

Tags: ros, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to run ORB_SLAM with my own drone.
when typing  `roslaunch SLAM SLAM.launch`in the terminal, I got an error that has never seen before as follows:

```
process[SLAM-1]: started with pid [13284]
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'rosbag::BagIOException'
  what():  Error opening file: 
[SLAM-1] process has died [pid 13284, exit code -6, cmd /home/htf/orb_ws/src/SLAM/bin/SLAM /home/htf/orb_ws/src/SLAM/Data/ORBvoc.txt /home/htf/orb_ws/src/SLAM/Data/Drone.yaml __name:=SLAM __log:=/home/htf/.ros/log/b3cdf97a-c6ef-11e8-bd1c-80a589d234a5/SLAM-1.log].
log file: /home/htf/.ros/log/b3cdf97a-c6ef-11e8-bd1c-80a589d234a5/SLAM-1*.log
all processes on machine have died, roslaunch will exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
```

here is the launch file:

```
<launch>
  <node name="SLAM" pkg="SLAM" type="SLAM" args="/home/htf/orb_ws/src/SLAM/Data/ORBvoc.txt /home/htf/orb_ws/src/SLAM/Data/Drone.yaml"/>
 
</launch>
```

does anyone know how to fix it? thanks a lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/304742/terminate-called-after-throwing-an-instance-of-%27rosbag::bagioexception%27---what():--error-opening-file:/) by [tengfei han](https://answers.ros.org/users/35120/tengfei-han/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-10-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not familiar with orb slam, but the error is that it is failing to open a bag file. You should check your configuration to make sure that all your paths are right and that you have permissions on any directory where it's going to try to read a bag or write a bag file. Sometimes it uses the current working directory too.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0